# :before gets placed above (instead of to the left) when element contains block elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a pseudo element that I'd like to have placed to the left of it's pertaining element (`.alpha`).

But when that element contains a block element (`.beta`), the pseudo element gets placed above everything.

Is there a workaround for this or is it impossible to have block elements inside an element with pseudo-element?

Here's a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/xs1s8Lee/).

```
<div class='alpha'>
  <div class='beta'>paragraph text</div>
</div>

.alpha:before {
    content: "this is ";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: This would of course be absolutely the same if it wasn’t a pseudo element, but a regular element such as a span or an image.

Comment: Thanks, should of course have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method # 01:**

Use an `inline` element for class `.beta` like `span`, `em` etc. in your code.

```css
.alpha:before {
    content: "this is ";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class='alpha'>
  <span class='beta'>paragraph text</span>
</div>
```

**Method # 02:**

Add `float: left` with some `margin-right` on your pseudo element and set its layout if you have mixture of `inline` and `block` elements inside parent.

```css
.alpha {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.alpha:before {
    content: "this is ";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-right: 4px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='alpha'>
  <div class='beta'>
  paragraph text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I understand this is possible, but enforcing `inline` on all child elements doesn't feel perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.alpha:before {
    content: "this is ";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.beta {display:inline;}
```

By making the beta div no longer a block element, you achieve your desired behaviour.

https://jsfiddle.net/xs1s8Lee/1/

Comment: Yes I understand this is possible, but enforcing `inline` on all child elements doesn't feel perfect.